# how does not hide the search bar when scrolling ? SwiftUi

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

**IOS 15 added** `.searchable(text: $searchtext)`

when I open my application, the search is hidden by default and only appears when scrolling the page, how can I open the application to immediately display the search?

**SWIFTUI IOS 15**

Comment: Do you have any code example of what you have tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In SwiftUI we have to set placement parameter in searchable modifier to .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always) it's makes always show search bar**

```
.searchable(text: $searchtext, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always)) {
    "your code"
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).